# How to pass the return value as the 2nd parameter in celery chain()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

```
def method2(p1, p2):
    ...

from celery import chain

res = chain(method1.s("X", "Y"), method2.s("Z"))()
```

So I want the result from `method1.s("X", "Y")` to be passed as `p2` of `method2()`, how to do that? By default, it is assigned to `p1` and `"Z"` is assigned to `p2`.

Answer (score 2):

As I see for now its impossible bcs of that in chain apply method in builtins.py:

```
      res = signature(task, app=app).clone(fargs).apply(
            last and (last.get(), ),
        )
```

Perhaps you will need to do that without chain something like:

```
res = method1.apply("X", "Y")
method2.apply("Z", res.result)
```